# Protecting Range through Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to protect a range through google apps script in my google sheet. Whenever the data point in column O is checked i.e. value is yes. I would like that row be protected.
Secondly, I have prior protected columns E:H and M:N, which should stay protected.
There are around 1000 rows, 10-15 new rows that need to be protected daily. By the code I have currently written, it removes the protection and then re-adds it, which takes a lot of time. If I remove the part where it removes the rights then it still re-adds the same protection regardless.

Is there anyway to check if the cell is protected, if protected move onto the next row?

Secondly, I'm unable to provide access to the other emails i.e. "add editors"

```
function removecompleted(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var purchased = ss.getSheetByName("Purchased Inventory")
  last_row_purchased = purchased.getLastRow()
  var emails = [
    'user@domain.com'
  ];

var protections = purchased.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
}

  for(var i = 1; i < last_row_purchased; i++) {
    if(purchased.getRange(i, 15).getValue() == "Yes")
    {
      target_range = purchased.getRange(i, 1, 1, 15)
      protection = target_range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
      protection.addEditors(emails);

protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}



    }
  }
var range = purchased.getRange('E:H');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Always Protected');
var range = purchased.getRange('M:N');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Always Protected');
}
```

Comment: If someone knows a better way to solve it too that would be amazing

Comment: I cannot understand `if protected move onto the next row?` and `Secondly, I'm unable to provide access to the other emails i.e. "add editors"`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: by if protected move onto next row, I meant that if that range has been already protected then it should not again protect the same row. Which it was currently doing. Secondly for the add editors, I need certain people to still have access to the range. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on edit, but rather than checking to see if the cell is protected (which is not that much faster than just setting the protection anyway) you can just check the row of each protected range and remove the protection if its row is equal to the row of the cell that was just unticked:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // List of sheet names the function should run on
  const sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "etc"]

  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()

  // if current sheet is not in permitted sheets, return
  if (!~sheets.indexOf(sheet.getName())) {
    return
  }

  const row = e.range.getRow()

  if (e.range.getColumn() === 15) { 
    const ss = e.source
    
    if (e.value === "TRUE") {
      range = sheet.getRange(`${row}:${row}`)
      const me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
      const protection = range.protect()
      protection.getEditors().forEach(user => {
        protection.removeEditor(user.getEmail())
      })
      protection.addEditor(me)
    }
    else {
      const protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
      protections.forEach(function(p) {
        if (p.getRange().getRow() === row) {
          if (row === 1 && p.getRange().getColumn() !== 1) return
          p.remove()
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

#### Code Rundown:

- Get the row number of the edited range
- Check if the edited cell was column 15
- If the value of the cell is `"TRUE"`, protect the row, and remove all editors aside yourself.
- If the value of the cell is `"FALSE"`, then get all the sheet's protections, check the value of their row, and if the row matches the edited cell's row, then remove that protection

NB : The final check also has a condition to check if the column is not equal to 1 so to not remove the protections on `E:H` or `M:N`.

References:

- [Class `Protection`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Class: `Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class: `Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: This would be an amazingly helpful solution. Wouldn't doing an on edit make the sheet extremely heavy and slow? Or is that a misconception? Would it track any and all edits or only edits on that particular tab? The Sheet I'm using has around 10-12 tabs, and I'm going to have the protection running for 3-4 tabs. But wouldn't want an edit in the others to affect this

Comment: onEdit triggers run fast enough that for most cases it won't slow the sheet down. With a guard statement at the beginning of the function you can just make it exit if the edited sheet isn't one of your deired ones. I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: In line 3 of the code we're selecting the sheets this code should run for but in line 17. We're saying to protect on sheet 1 not the respective sheets itself. Is this an error or by design? Because say sheet 2 was the sheet that was edited, that should be the sheet which is protected too.

Comment: The person who edits the data should also be removed, it should be the owner of the document - myself and another email id(username@domain.com), which have access to the protected range thereafter.

Comment: @KaranSaraogi was a minor error I left in during testing. I've edited the code now - but yes instead of being Sheet1 you should assign it to the active sheet from the event object.

Comment: @KaranSaraogi as for the extra editor - just add `protection.addEditor("their_email@address.here")` after the `protection.addEditor(me)` line.